# Java Advanced Imaging GradientMagnitudeDescriptor

Tags: java, image-processing, gradient, jai, descriptor

I have been reading the API and documentation (http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jai1_0_1guide-unc/Analysis.doc.html 9.5 Edge Detection) and have come across the GradientMagnitudeDescriptor class. Thing is, the create() Method of this class returns a static RenderedOp (whatever that is).

How do I deal with this static RenderedOp in terms of extracting coordinates?

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I am completely new to image processing and analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Listing 9-4 Example GradientMagnitude Operation](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jai1_0_1guide-unc/Analysis.doc.html#56654) and see if that helps any. You don't call the `create` method on the `GradientMagnitudeDescriptor` class, instead you call the `JAI.create()` method with the "GradientMagnitude" operation name. `JAI.create()` returns an instance of `RenderedOp` which can be cast to `PlanarImage` if you want.